# I can't understand why SettingWithCopyWarning is happened

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, chained

I tried to rolling function to dataframe extracted.

```
df = pd.read_csv('ExchangeRate_2020-08-24.csv' , index_col = 'Date', parse_dates = True)
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Date'])
df_sorted_KtoU = df_sorted[df_sorted['price'] == 'KRW/USD']
df_sorted_UtoE = df_sorted[df_sorted['price'] == 'USD/EUR']
df_sorted_KtoU['Rate : 20Day Mean'] = df_sorted_KtoU['Rate'].rolling(window=20, min_periods = 1).mean()
df_sorted_KtoU.head()
```

I can get a right answer but it's warning,

---

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
after removing the cwd from sys.path.

---

How can I code better?

Futhermore,

```
df_sorted_KtoU['Rate', 'Rate : 20Day Mean'].plot(figsize = (15,8), ylim = (1000,1250))
```

it is not working at all T.T

Please help me

Comment: There are filter, so need `df_sorted_KtoU = df_sorted[df_sorted['price'] == 'KRW/USD'].copy()`

Comment: Wow.. Thank you very much. Then why last code is not working??

Comment: there is no loc, need `df_sorted_KtoU.loc['Rate', 'Rate : 20Day Mean'].plot(figsize = (15,8), ylim = (1000,1250))`

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it is not working too, so I tried '''df_sorted_KtoU[['Rate', 'Rate : 20Day Mean']].plot(figsize = (15,8), ylim = (1000,1250)) ''' so it is success. I think it was not list format, so that error was happened